# JavaScript sliding functionality for two divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am writing a simple JS functionality.
When I click the red color div, I want yellow and green color div to go under it with a simple sliding and both yellow and green should not be visible since they will be hiding behind red.
Similarly when I click back the red div, the green and yellow div should open up with same sliding functionality.

I am trying to achieve similar kind of slide movement as in the following URL.

[animated-playing-cards](http://www.sebastien-laframboise.com/free-animated-playing-cards/)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CfEj4/6/)

```
var whatever = document.getElementById("whatever");

Array.prototype.push.apply((whateversChildren = []), whatever.children);
whateversChildren.splice(0,1);

whatever.children[0].onclick = (function() {

    if (whatever.children.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < whateversChildren.length; i++) {
            whatever.removeChild(whateversChildren[i]);
            whatever.firstElementChild.appendChild(whateversChildren[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < whateversChildren.length; i++) {
            whatever.firstElementChild.removeChild(whateversChildren[i]);
            whatever.appendChild(whateversChildren[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you're trying to achieve? What do you mean "when I click back"?

Comment: @Intredasting: when i click back the red div it should open up again with green and yellow div in a slide movement

Comment: What do you mean by "slide"? You want to move them around from position x to position y and finally behind the red?

Comment: Like this http://www.sebastien-laframboise.com/free-animated-playing-cards/

Comment: Ah, so you do not want to expand the red div, but slide green and yellow behind the red as it is.

Comment: you can use jquery animate and toggle function for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tagged this JavaScript I'm following the tags description and:

*Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.*

This could be a start. Relies upon transition in CSS and JavaScript to calculate some left positions.

Transition is set on *"all"* which mean any style property changed will change by the *time* given. In code sample it is set to 0.75 seconds.

<kbd>***[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/c5WuM/)***</kbd>

CSS:

```
#whatever div {
    position   : relative; /* Added. For movement and z-index */
    transition : all .75s; /* Added. For animation/slide */
}

#c1 {
    z-index : 10;         /* Added. To keep it atop. */
    cursor  : pointer;    /* Added. For nicety. */
}

.show {
    opacity : 1;
}
.hide {
    opacity : 0.3;
    z-index : 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function Slider(id) {
    var box = document.getElementById(id);
    // CSS class names
    this.css = {
        show : 'show',
        hide : 'hide'
    };
    // Array holding left position for each element.
    this.pos = [];
    // Get all the children
    this.ch  = box.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
    this.ch[0].onclick = this.click.bind(this);
    // Get initial positions.
    this.fillPos();
    // Make sure to add class show.
    this.show();
}
// Find left position of an element.
Slider.prototype.left = function(e) {
    var x = e.offsetLeft;
    while (e = e.offsetParent) {
        x += e.offsetLeft;
    }
    return x;
};
// Get left position for all elements.
Slider.prototype.fillPos = function() {
    var i;
    this.pos = [];
    for (i = 0; i < this.ch.length; ++i) {
        this.pos.push(
            this.left(this.ch[i])
        );
    }    
};
// Show
Slider.prototype.show = function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < this.ch.length; ++i) {
        this.ch[i].className = this.css.show;
        this.ch[i].style.left = '0';
    }
};
// Hide
Slider.prototype.hide = function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < this.ch.length; ++i) {
        this.ch[i].className = this.css.hide;
        // Set left equal to left minus left position of first (red) element.
        this.ch[i].style.left = -(this.pos[i] - this.pos[0]) + 'px';
    }
};
// Event handler.
Slider.prototype.click = function(e) {
    if (this.ch[1].className === 'hide')
        this.show();
    else
        this.hide();
};

// Create new slider
var sly = new Slider("whatever");
```

Comment: thank u so much for your reply...i am trying to achieve one more thing... When I click the button, the green and yellow div closes but the c4 and c5 should also open up. Right now I have hidden it.. http://jsfiddle.net/c5WuM/11/

Comment: @user3299657: It is hard to go any further without knowing the over all goal, what "content" is, why you have some div's outside the "whatever" and some inside, if they can be of fixed size or not and so on.

Comment: @user3299657: Nah, Had a look at it, but only as a test. http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/dw35y/ Would do a lot of changes to it. Guess it would probably be better to use absolute positioned instead of relative. If there is only a few products it would also be better to build them all at once and flip them around instead of replacing the HTML.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49548/discussion-between-user3299657-and-user13500)

Comment: There is no `...can` at end of it. Or try to F5 on the previous link.

Comment: even the previous links are not working :(

Comment: Oh, crap. Perhaps I deleted wrong fiddle. Thought I deleted a fork that I discontinued.

Comment: Can u send the fiddle

Comment: can you pls reply for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368390/click-functionality-to-be-called-in-html?noredirect=1#comment34002295_22368390