# Click functionality to be called in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have js functionality where a html tag is generated in js and a click function is associated with it. Right now I am trying to attach my js functionality to my generated html, but I don't know how to implement it. I have provided my code below.

When I click the select button the animation effect should take place, but I don't know how to associate the function `UversePlanSelector.prototype.click` with the select button.

[Not working code](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3nsR/)

[Working code](http://jsfiddle.net/Cs8kh/2/)

```
<div class="plan">
  <div class="plan_head"><span class="hdr">Max plus</span><span class="tag">$54.95</span>
  </div>
  <div class="plan_spec"><span class="hdr">18 / 3</span> Mbps</div>
  <button>Select</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain the relationship between "Not working code", "Working code" and the code that you pasted directly?

Comment: @kobejohn: thanks for your reply in working code when you click the slect button an animation effect takes place...where as in non working code when i click the select button the animation effect does not takes place...i am trying to cll the same functionality in my non working code